# How can I use url to get the tumblr user/info

Tags: tumblr

I try to use api.tumblr.com/v2/user/info to fetch the user info, but it shows {"meta":{"status":401,"msg":"Not Authorized"},"response":[]}. what should I append in the url?

Comment: "Use this method to retrieve the user's account information that matches the OAuth credentials submitted with the request." http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#user-methods

Answer (score 0):

you can Use this method to retrieve the user's account information that matches the **OAuth credentials submitted** with the request.
visit this link for more information
http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2